# SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null and URL is correct

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to put an Image from a URL in a ImageView, but I keep getting the "SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null" error.

Here's my code:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String myUrl= urls[0];

        Bitmap myBmp= null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            myBmp= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return myBmp;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** logcat when the app crashes after getting the first image
[logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuf8m.png)

```
public class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<String> values;

static class ViewHolder {

    private TextView textViewName;
    private TextView textViewType;
    private ImageView imageView;
}

public customAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_member, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder mViewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_member, parent, false);
        mViewHolder.textViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        mViewHolder.textViewType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        mViewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    }
    else {
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    String s = values.get(position);
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "*");
    String name = st.nextToken();
    String url_photo = st.nextToken();
    String type = st.nextToken();
    if (type.equals("CHILD")) {
        String count_dev = st.nextToken();
        mViewHolder.textViewType.setText(count_dev);
    }
    else {
        mViewHolder.textViewType.setText(type);
    }
    mViewHolder.textViewName.setText(name);
    new DownloadImageTask(mViewHolder.imageView).execute(url_photo);
    return convertView;
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String urlStr = urls[0];
        Bitmap img = null;

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlStr);
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = (HttpResponse)client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity bufferedEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
            InputStream inputStream = bufferedEntity.getContent();
            img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return img;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
}
```

As requested, this is the full code for this class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this code in your background method:

```
   protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String urlStr = params[0];
                Bitmap img = null;

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlStr);
                HttpResponse response;
                try {
                    response = (HttpResponse)client.execute(request);           
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    BufferedHttpEntity bufferedEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                    InputStream inputStream = bufferedEntity.getContent();
                    img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return img;
            }
```

Comment: HttpClient canot be resolved and getContent cannot be resolved. How do I import the correct Libraries?

Comment: add imports for it then, adding imports is necessary

Comment: I added it, and it loads the first Image, but it crashes without opening the next ones, any idea why?

Comment: check the logcat for errors, post the full source code you are using.

Comment: the next element is throwing a null value, find it out.